# Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and size $m$. If $m>n$, then $G$ contains at least one cycle.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and size $m$. If $m>n$, then $G$ contains at least one cycle.

Any idea how to do this problem? Please help. Thanks

Comment: A tree has $m=n-1$. Inserting any more edges connects two nodes that were already connected to each other via some path in the tree, and we get a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

## Claim:

For a connected graph $G$, with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, $G$ contains atleast one cycle if $m \geq n$.

## Proof:

This can be proved using induction on the number of vertices, $n$.

Base case ($n=1$): The claim holds for $n=1$, because $n = 1 \implies m \geq 1$. If $m = 1$, there is a self loop.

**Induction hypothesis:** Assume the claim is valid for $n = k$ and we show that the claim is also valid for $n = k+1$.

Let $\delta$ denote the minimum of the degree of all vertices in G.

Now we prove the claim for the following three cases ($\delta = 0, \delta = 1, \delta \geq 2$):

**Case I:** $\delta = 0$.

Since $\delta = 0$, there exists at least one vertex $v$, such that $deg(v) = 0$. Delete this vertex from $G$.
The new graph $(G-v)$ contains $k$ vertices and $m$ edges. Moreover,

$$m \geq k + 1 \implies m \geq k$$

Therefore $(G-v)$ contains at least one cycle. This implies $G$ contains atleast one cycle.

**Case II:** $\delta = 1$

There exists at least one vertex $v$, such that, $deg(v) = 1$. The graph $(G-v)$ contains $k$ vertices and $m-1$ edges.

$$m \geq k+1 \implies m-1 \geq k$$

Therefore, $(G-v)$ contains at least one cycle. This implies, $G$ contains atleast one cycle.

**Case III:** $\delta \geq 2$

$\delta \geq 2 \implies$ every vertex $v_i \in G$ is connected to two edges.

Lets start a walk from $v_0$. With the following rules:

- Enter a vertex through one edge and exit through a different edge.
- The walk ends when a previously visited vertex is visited again.

NOTE: Walk ends $\implies$ there exists a cycle.

Since every vertex has at least two edges, it always possible to enter a vertex and leave the vertex. The only way a walk can end is if it revisits a previously visited vertex. Since there are only finite number of vertices the walk has to end. Therefore this implies $G$ contains a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two methods; one is to use the same induction method as Ramasamy Kandasamy, but it is enough to use minimum degree $<2$ and $\ge 2$.

Another method is to use cut edges. Once we take these, "there are no cycles" means all the edges are cut edges. Then, deletion of all the $m$ edges must give $m+1$ components with at least one vertex (if it is originally disconnected, use the connected component).

i.e., $n=m+1$ is a contradiction of $m\ge n$. Hence proved.

Answer (score -1):

The proof is essentially by counting, and it is a standard tutorial question in graph theory or discrete mathematics.

So suppose $G$ has order $n$ and size $m$. That means, it has $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. If $m>n$, then you have more edges and vertices, and for $n$ vertices, the best you can do without forming cycles is to connect every vertex with an edge to form a straight string. But this at most uses only $n-1$ edges, as you should verify. So you are left with at least 2 edges (since $m>n$ implies $m\geq n+1$), and therefore the only way to use the edges is to connect two vertices which are already connected by an edge (you should bend the string to help you see this when you try to connect the remaining edges). This forms the required cycle.