# Is my proof for "if $m \geq n$, then G contains a cycle" right?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I found an answer for the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676120/let-g-be-a-graph-of-order-n-and-size-m-if-mn-then-g-contains-at-lea), but I don't use induction to prove the statement. Since I'm a beginner in graph theory and proofs in general, I would like some feedback on the solution I found (the book I use doesn't provide solutions...). A disclaimer regarding notation: the book refers to any graph with just one vertex as a *trivial graph*.

**Claim.** If $e(G) \geq v(G)$, then $G$ contains a cycle.

**Proof.** We prove the contrapositive. Suppose $G$ is acyclic. If $G$ is a trivial graph, then $e(G) < v(G)$. If $G$ is nontrivial, consider the following cases: 
*Case 1*: $G$ is connected. Let $P$ be a path in $G$. Then, $e(P) = v(P) - 1 < v(P)$ [1]. Since $G$ is acyclic, any edges that are not in $E(P)$ contribute with one new vertex not in $V(P)$ (otherwise we'd form a cycle). Thus, inequality [1] holds for every vertices and edges of $G$. 
*Case 2*: $G$ is disconnected. The same arguments holds for all $n$ components of $G$. Let $G_i$ be the i-th component of $G$. Then, $e(G_i) < v(G_i)$. Therefore, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} e(G_i) < \sum_{i=1}^{n} v(G_i) \therefore e(G) < v(G)$.

I know I'm being verbose and (probably) even redundant at some points. But I wanted to write every single detail so I could receive more feedback on proof writing, etc.

Thanks for any feedback! :)

Comment: Are you at all familiar with trees? In particular, do you know about the theorem stating that $n = m + 1$, where $n$ and $m$ are, respectively, the number of vertices and edges in a given tree $T$?

Comment: Yes I know this theorem! But I learned about it in the context of algorithms. In my book of graph theory, this theorem will show up afterwards, so let's say I had to "pretend" I didn't know about it (my professor thought it'd be a good exercise). xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ideas you have are correct, and I like that you noted that it basically suffices to prove the claim for connected graph; this is quite a common technique in graph theory. However, "Since $G$ is acyclic, any edges that are not in $E(P)$ contribute with one new vertex not in $V(P)$" seems a bit informal.

Here is my quick attempt at making it slightly more formal/clear.
Since $G$ is acyclic and connected, every vertex $v$ not in $V(P)$ can be reached by a unique path $P_{uv}:=ue_1u_1e_2u_2\dots e_ku_k$ with the starting vertex $u$ in $V(P)$, where $u_k=v$. Thus, we can form an injective map from edges not in $E(P)$ to vertices not in $V(P)$, namely $e_i\mapsto u_i$. Hence, $|V(G)|-|V(P)|\geq |E(G)|-E(P)|$. Combining this with your first inequality, we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)